# Where is "MediaWiki:Vector.css" of my MediaWiki

Tags: css, mediawiki

I want to install [Skin:Vector-DarkCSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector-DarkCSS) on my `MediaWiki`. It must be simple, but second step of installation instructions syas I have to edit `MediaWiki:Vector.css` on my wiki. I searched for file with name `MediaWiki:Vector.css`, but could not found in `MediaWiki` home. Where is that file? Do I need to create that?

Comment: This question is better suited to a mediawiki forum than a webmasters forum.

Comment: @Steve But I think it is relative to this QA site too.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Steve Thank you! But in linked page there is: `There are specific Stack Exchange sites for several CMSs. Use those sites for Craft CMS, Drupal, ... . Questions about other CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.`

Comment: Fair enough, the moderators will decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a question in [superuser](https://superuser.com/) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1152790/140047) was correct:

> MediaWiki:Vector.css is not a file on your filessytem. Its "just" a
>   Wikipage. Just type "MediaWiki:Vector.css" in the searchbar and create
>   this Wikipage.
>
> After this MediaWiki:Vector.css will be embedded in your css.